# Intel UHD620 lagging in playing 4k videos from YouTube

Tags: firefox, google-chrome, intel-graphics, youtube

I have a Intel I3 8130U cpu with intel UHD 620 and videos in 4k from youtube are lagging(Ubuntu 22.04).I was looking in system monitor and all the cores where used at max.I was trying to watch with firefox(with chrome is the same).In Windows 11 i dont have problems watching same videos with same browser.The CPU usage was 70% at max. PS:i have 12GB of RAM .
I was trying another distro with kernel 6.1 and the videos are playing the same(laggy).
Any help is much appreciated.
Tried with Ubuntu 23.04 and its even worse(cant play 1080p from youtube) with kernel version 6.2.0-20-generic
LE: Tried with Ubuntu 20.04 LTS and kernel version 5.15.0-67-generic and works like a charm.
LEE:In some videos is still lagging so the problem is still there.